# Does "the scratch is on the left of your eye" mean "it's on the left part of your eye" or "it's on the left part near your eye"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

When we say "**you have a scratch on the left of your eye**",

Does it mean "**the scratch is on the left part of your eye**" (which is very serious, you need to see a doctor) or "**the scratch is on the left part near your eye**" (which is not serious, you don't need to go see a doctor)?

Comment: I believe that is not called a eye scratch, because that is something different. In the image it looks like a mole. Moles are found both on the skin as well as in the eye. Medical term is Nevus (plural nevi). However I am not sure regarding the location they tried to describe in the sentence. But as far as I can interpret, "you have a scratch on the left of your eye" would literally mean you have a scratch to the left of your eye.

Comment: If someone wants to describe the fact that there is a mole or nevus in the eye, they would probably say, "You have a mole in your right/left eye". And if it really is a scratch, one would use the similar sentences to describe the situation. "You have a scratch (on the left side) in your left eye" to denote inside property. OR "You have a scratch on the left side of your eye" which can also be written as "You have a scratch to the left of your eye".

Comment: What you've written is not immediately understandable.  It's either *You have a scratch **on the left side** of your eye.*  Or it's *You have a scratch **to** the left of your [left] eye.*  *On the eye* means on the eyeball or eyelid.  *To the left of* means on the face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the speaker, it could mean either. In context, and if a native speaker produced it, it would usually be understood as near the eye, not on the eye, i.e. "on the left of" = "to the left of".

In everyday speech, 'he's got a scratch next to his right eye' would be perfectly sufficient to describe the scratch you have illustrated---if it were on the other side of the eye, I would say 'between his eyes' or 'on the bridge of his nose'.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is not called a eye scratch, because that is something different. In the image it looks like a mole. Moles are found both on the skin as well as in the eye. Medical term is Nevus (plural nevi).

"You have a scratch on the left of your eye" would literally mean you have a scratch to the left of your eye.

If someone wants to describe the fact that there is a mole or nevus in the eye, they would probably say, "You have a mole in your right/left eye". And if it really is a scratch, one would use the similar sentence to describe the situation. "You have a scratch (on the left side) in your left eye" to denote it is inside.

Otherwise, "You have a scratch on the left side of your eye" which can also be written as "You have a scratch to the left of your eye" to mean it is outside the eye dimensions.

---

<sub>I certainly did not just copy paste and frame my own words in accordance to the already provided answer. I had commented the same thing only minutes after the question was posted. To all the down-voters who just look who answered first and whether others copied theirs, PLEASE NOTE. I wrote this because I have seen such behaviour here on ELL as well as other sites of SE.</sub>

Comment: One would say, *You have a mole in your eye*.  No one would say, *You have a scratch in your eye.*  They would say, *You have a scratch on your eye.*

Comment: @EllieK Agreed. I already have once instance mentioned in my answer, your first suggestion that is. However, I am no medical student or practitioner, hence I am unaware of many medical conditions. Hence I thought there might exist something like a scratch that is present or found inside the eye as well. Other conditions resulted because of animals or birds or other activities, are well, as you said, _on your eye_. If you don't mind I will take your last suggestion to add in my answer.